# I need an explanation about a this equation

Tags: c

```
 while(v!=0)
{
        temp=u%v;
        u=v;
        v=temp;
}
```

I couldn't understand this equation.Why there is u=v and also v=temp.
how can this equation find greatest common devisor.And what does temp mean?

Comment: You need to write at least like while(v!=0)
{   
    temp=u%v;
    u=v;
    v=temp;
}

Comment: `temp` is a variable. It holds the new value of `v` while the old value of `v` is copied to `u`.

Comment: @Tanveer - [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Euclidean_algorithm)

Answer (score 2):

The algorihm is called "euclidian algorithm" (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)).

Let `x` be the greatest common divisor (gcd) of `u` and `v` and `u > v`.

Then `x` is also gcd of `v` and `u-v`.

In the algorithm, you keep subtracting the smaller number from the larger number until one of them becomes the gcd `x`.

The `temp = u % v` means `u` modulo `v` (subtracting `v` from `u` as often as possible)

So after this step you have smaller numbers `temp` and `v` than you started with, that have the same gcd.
The smaller value is now in `temp`, so `temp < v`, otherwise you could continue subtracting.

To be able to reuse the code, you have to make sure the larger value is in `u` and the smaller value is in `v`, so `v` becomes your new `u` and `temp` becomes you new `v`.

To break the loop `v` (`temp`) has to become `0`. To reach `0`, `u` must be a multiple of `v` before the modulo operation.
The gcd of a number and its multiple is the number itself, so `v` stored to `u` in this case.

Since over all the time the gcd `x` of the numbers did not change, we finally have `u == x`.

This scheme with `temp` is commonly used to swap two values.

```
    temp=a;
    a=b;
    b=temp;
```